# Javascript array not creating an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with items and I want to group them according the first letter but when I push the item to the array it shows empty "Array[0]" while there are clearly items in it.

Apparently I'm doing something wrong but i have no idea what.

```js
var group = [];
var alphabetArray = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split('');
alphabetArray.forEach(function(letter) {
  group[letter] = group[letter] || [];
  group[letter].push({
    key: letter,
    letter
  });
});
console.log(group);
```

Comment: "group them according the first letter" -  what do you mean? some kind of sort?

Comment: The original array is an array which contains user data

Comment: Please provide an expected result for input string `AB`, just for first two characters. I still have no idea what exactly are you looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are designed to hold an *ordered set of data* represented by **property names which are integers**.

You are assigning property names which are **letters**.

Arrays are not designed to hold that kind of data and `console.log` doesn't display those properties for arrays.

---

Don't use an array. Use an object. Objects are designed to hold unordered data with arbitrary property names. If order matters, then you might want to use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead.

Comment: Well, the names aren't integers (in that they're not numbers), but close enough. They're strings consisting of a series of digits denoting an integer in canonical format whose numeric value `i` is in the range `+0 ≤ i < 2^32-1`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to create an object instead of an array. Change the [] to {}

An Array expects an int as index, the object can take a string

```js
var group = {}; // Object instead of Array
var alphabetArray = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split('');
alphabetArray.forEach(function(letter) {
  group[letter] = group[letter] || [];
  group[letter].push({
    key: letter,
    letter
  });
});
console.log(group);
```

Comment: That works up to the point when i want to iterate through it in Angular 2 with ngFor

Comment: You really should mention that in question, that's [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to transform each letter to structure. I f so, you need `Array.map`:

```js
var alphabetArray = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split('');
var group = alphabetArray.map(function(letter) {
  return {
    [letter]: letter
  };
});
console.log(group);
```